# Angular JS Concept 'Separation Of Concerns' --> CRUD Screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a two CRUD screens in AngularJS.

1) Separate html file for View, Add and Edit. View Controller, Add Controller and Edit Controllers also Separate. This structure creating more duplicate code in html and controller side.

2) Separate html file for View, Add. View Controller, Add Controller only Separate. During edit mode I'm using a Boolean in controller to find its in edit mode or not.

I'm new to AngularJS. Anybody clearly tell me pros and cons, which way is correct in AngularJS 'Separation Of Concerns' concept.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you're going to the good direction.

By separation of concern, what is intended is to split the code that is responsible for managing the view, and the code responsible to make calls to your server. Imagine you want to make CRUD around a person, I would do the following :

**service :**

```
angular.module('app').factory("personService", ["$http", function($http)]){
    return {
        create : create,
        update: update,
        remove : remove,
        get: get
    };

    function create(person){
        return http.post("person/create", person);
    }
    // other functions
}
```

Then, I would only have 1 **controller** for everything :

```
angular.module("app").controller("PersonController", ["personService", function(personService)]){
    var self = this;

    self.isUpdate = true; // Insert logic here
    self.isCreate = false; // Insert logic here

    init();

    self.save = function(){
        var promise = self.isCreate ? 
                          personService.create(self.person)
                         :personService.update(self.person);

        promise.then(function(result){
            // Handle return of save;
        });

    };

    function init(){
        if (!self.isCreate){
            personService.get(personId).then(function(result){
                self.person = result.data.person;
            });
        }
    }

}
```

And then I would have the following **view** :

```
<div ng-controller="personController as person">
    <label>Name: </label>
    <input type="text" ng-disabled="!person.isUpdate" ng-model="person.person.name" />

    <button ng-click="person.isUpdate = !person.isUpdate;">Edit</button>
    <!-- Edit : the code 'person.isUpdate = !person.isUpdate;' could also be into a controller's function (like the save function) -->

    <button ng-click="person.save()" ng-if="person.isUpdate">Save</save>
</div>
```

I also recommend you to read this : https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

Answer (score 1):

Separation of concerns means that you have a well defined structure of your application: the data model in the application is decoupled from the business and presentation logic. It is the base of the MVC pattern, which defines the view, the controller and the model.
This separation makes the code maintainable and easy to test.

Follow this guidance how to architect your Angular application.

The **model should**:

1. Include the domain data;
2. Implement the management of the domain data (query, edit, delete, storing mechanism, REST implementation, http fetching);
3. Expose an API that makes possibly the model usage in controller or other service;

The **model should not**:

1. Provide the details on how the domain data is managed (all REST implementation, http calls should be encapsulated in the model);
2. Contain logic that transforms the model based on user interaction (it is controller's role);
3. Contain logic for displaying data to the user (this is the view’s job);

A **controller should**:

1. Contain the logic required to initialize the scope;
2. Contain the logic/behaviors required by the view to present data from the scope;
3. Contain the logic/behaviors required to update the scope based on user interaction;

A **controller should not**:

1. Contain logic that manipulates the DOM (that is the job of the view);
2. Contain logic that manages the persistence of data (that is the job of the model);
3. Manipulate data outside of the scope;

A **view should**:

1. Contain the logic and markup required to present data to the user

A **view should not**:

1. Contain complex logic (this is better placed in a controller);
2. Contain logic that creates, stores, or manipulates the domain model.

This guidance is taken from [this awesome book](http://www.apress.com/9781430264484), which I recommend for any starting AngularJS developer.

Related to your example, in my opinion you should:

1. Create a controller and a template for editing and adding; Depending on model's `isNew` property, you can apply editing or adding action;
2. Create a controller and a template for viewing the model;
3. Optionally, if you have a collection of models, you can create a new controller and view also.

However it depends on the amount of logic behind the model. If the model is trivial, probably you can implement everything in a single controller and view. But it's rare.

Comment: I have planned to use, 2 html pages (view and add). also 2 controllers for view and add. Create and Edit process will be available in add screen and controller.

Comment: @SureshArumugam Yep, probably one for add and edit, and one for preview.